# Setting up localstack resources in docker compose file results in connection aborted failure

Tags: docker-compose, localstack

I have a docker compose file that looks like the following:

```
version: "3"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    ports:
      - "4567-4597:4567-4597"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/private${TMPDIR}:/tmp/localstack"
    networks:
      - my_awesome_network

  setup-resources:
    image: mesosphere/aws-cli
    volumes:
      - ./dev_env:/project/dev_env
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummyaccess
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummysecret
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    command: >
      "
        sleep 10;
        # aws kinesis create-stream --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4568 --stream-name my_stream --shard-count 1;
        aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 mb s3://demo-bucket
      "
    networks:
      - my_awesome_network
    depends_on:
      - localstack
networks:
  my_awesome_network:
```

which has been copied from [this](https://itnext.io/docker-compose-aws-localstack-why-not-both-fc8a1db84eca) blog post that I have found, but when I run `docker-compose up` the bucket fails to create with the following error: `('Connection aborted.', error(99, 'Address not available'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small detail here but it should not be `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 mb s3://demo-bucket`
it should instead be `aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4572 s3 mb s3://demo-bucket`, that's right `localhost` becomes `localstack`

Answer (score 3):

I ran it with small changes and it's correctly working, change the localhost to localstack

```
version: "3"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    ports:
      - '4568-4576:4568-4576'
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - DEBUG=1
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/private${TMPDIR}:/tmp/localstack"
    networks:
      - my_awesome_network

  setup-resources:
    image: mesosphere/aws-cli
    volumes:
      - ./dev_env:/project/dev_env
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummyaccess
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummysecret
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    command: >
      "
        sleep 10;

        aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4572 s3 mb s3://demo-bucket
      "
    networks:
      - my_awesome_network
    depends_on:
      - localstack
networks:
  my_awesome_network:
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 0.11.0,
All APIs are exposed via a single edge service,
which is accessible on

`http://localhost:4566 by default`

and EDGE_PORT=4566.

Found on this
[Article](https://onexlab-io.medium.com/docker-compose-localstack-fadee1e88a49)

Comment: I mean thanks, but this doesn't really address the question

Comment: just a fun fact bruh